# How to user defined serialPort StopBits

Tags: c#, variables

My application is reading user created settings from an INI.  Everything works except that once the data from the INI is show in all the form's text box's, the sreialPort1 connection settings won't allow me to use some of the variables.

For some, I just needed to convert to an Int, so for example the below worked just fine:

```
serialPort1.BaudRate = Convert.ToInt32(txtboxbaud.Text);
```

However,  the following will not:

```
serialPort1.StopBits = Convert.ToInt32(txtboxstopbits.Text);
```

I receive the error "An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

I'm not sure what I need to do to fix it.

Comment: It looks like `serialPort1.StopBits` isn't of type `int`

Answer (score 5):

The StopBits Property is an enum, not an Int32. Look into https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.stopbits(v=vs.110).aspx

You could store its values as a string and use:

```
serialPort1.StopBits = (StopBits) Enum.Parse(typeof(StopBits), mystring);
```